# Cocos2d app not showing in full screen in ipad

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, fullscreen

My cocos2d ipad app loading properly in ipad. But after the default loading screen, it loads not in full screen.

```
  @implementation IntroLayer


 +(CCScene *) scene
 {  
 CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

 IntroLayer *layer = [IntroLayer node];

 [scene addChild: layer];

 return scene;
 }


 -(id) init
 {
if( (self=[super init])) {

    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCSprite *background;

    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        background.rotation = 90;
    } else {
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default-Landscape~ipad.png"];
    }
    background.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);

    [self addChild: background];
}

return self;
 }

 -(void) onEnter
 {
[super onEnter];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene] ]];
 }
  @end
```

Comment: check devices under target. It must be set to iPhone so you are not getting fullscreen.

Comment: iow: set the targeted devices for the app to "universal" ie  iphone+ipad

Comment: @Renaissance, LearnCocos2d are right. I set it to ipad. Then it show properly. Thanks a lot.